# ODATA component content

Tags: 2013, odata

Could I access to the content fields if I publish a component? 
In the table CustomMetas I can see all the fields I add in the MetaData component.
I can not get the fields I add in the content tag?

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tridion Content Delivery does not expose the content fields, it exposes something called a "Component Presentation", which is the result of rendering the components with your Component Templates.

A very common approach for fully dynamic application models (like DD4T) is to render the content of the component as structured data (using XML or JSON) and then loading/parsing this on the delivery side.

Short answer: no, you don't see the individual `Content` fields of your component, but you can render your components to output structured data instead of html.